# Javascript get mobile screen width after orientation change

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, screen-orientation

I am capturing the `orientationchange` event like this:

```
            $(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){

            });
```

How can I get the new screen width and height in pixels after the `orientationchage`?

I have tried `screen.width` but this doesn't change, it remains as the initial width, even after orientation change.

Comment: Have you seen the recommendations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508014/javascript-to-detect-mobile-browser-screen-width)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
    var ori = window.orientation,
        width = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? screen.height : screen.width;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this would be any *faster*, but there's the option of: `width = Math.abs(window.orientation) == 90 ? screen.height : screen.width;` Which at least saves assigning a variable and a double-assessment of the same variable. (But a +1 for switching to a ternary between my first seeing the question -on mobile- and commenting.)

Comment: @DavidThomas It's a micro-optimization. The only reason I added the `ori` variable was to keep the line from being too long.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use `screen.availWidth`. It gets changed with orientation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the meta tag viewport you could also update that tag (with jquery example:)

```
        function adapt_to_orientation() {
        var ori = window.orientation;
        var screenwidth = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? screen.height : screen.width;
        var screenheight = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? screen.width : screen.height;
                  // resize meta viewport
                  $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,width='+screenwidth + ',height=' + screenheight);
                }   
        adapt_to_orientation();
        $(window).bind( 'orientationchange', adapt_to_orientation);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **$(window).resize**, it runs after **orientationchange**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        //your logic
});
```

Comment: I voted this answer because previous answers are using previous widht and height ( the ones before rotation, i think the event is triggered right after the mobile is rotated while the window size (width) is still the same one). $(window).resize is triggered after the rotation is complete.