# Issues with EventListener Orientation change JavaScript

Tags: javascript, screen, orientation, screen-orientation

I'm trying to get the new page width on rotation using the an EventListener.

It works great when the page loads, and in the first rotation. After that it just doesn't update the value.

Here is my code:

```js
 window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
     outWindowWidth2 = window.innerWidth;
     w = outWindowWidth2
     setsizes(w);
     alert(w);
 }, false);
```

If I remove the call to the function it will always get the correct width.
Does anyone knows what might be causing this?

Thank you
Nuno

Comment: Screen `width` is never changed, You have to consider height when when orientation is landscape and vice versa..

Comment: Hi Rayon,

Thank you for your answer. 

The output for w seems to change whenever I rotate the screen. Also I only need the new screen width once the screen rotates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript get mobile screen width after orientation change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200135/javascript-get-mobile-screen-width-after-orientation-change)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to Rayon Dabre I got a solution for this:

```
 $(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e)
 { var ori = window.orientation, width = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? screen.height : screen.width;
    //alert(ori);
    setsizes(width);
 } );
```

Hope this helps other people!

Cheers
Nuno