# signed apk behaving weird

Tags: android

Recently I developed a launcher app for a Samsung tab 2 running android 4.0.3. During development/debugging everything was running fine. But when I created a release/signed apk we started experiencing problems with font rendering and the system home button not behaving properly.

Tested it again on the same tablet upgraded to 4.0.4 and everything was fine again.. can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I would say that this might be considered a little vague. IT might be good to show some screenshots of before and after. You might want to show some code too (if appropriate) as well as document the steps you are taking and what IDE/Tools.

Comment: Which tab 2,  the 7inch or the 10.1 inch

Comment: The 10 inch.. the big bug was that when ever you pressed the system bars home button it did nothing.. until we upgraded.. we have no code involving the home key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the Galaxy Tab 2 reported its pixel density as 170dpi and screen bucket of hdpi in 4.0.3 .  This was fixed in 4.0.4 to report as mdpi. I know this personally as I work on a comic reader application as was a pain in the ass to compensate for.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049934/794088) has way more definitive information.
I hope this helps you Erik.

Comment: thanks.. I don't know why this would affect the systembar's home button functionality, bu regardless,  we have tested it now on 5 different Samsung 10" tablets, and we get the bug on 4.0.3 and NOT on 4.0.4

Comment: as for that home button.  Trying to capture it would work on some devices and not on others. I never code for it anymore.  But that was few years and few craptastic devices ago.