# Samsung galaxy tab 3 10.1 screen density and resolution

Tags: android, android-drawable, screen-density

I need do create drawable folder for the tab in object Each drawables i've created for my app doesn't fit well on galaxy tab (it's too small respect screen). What is density and screen dimension of that tablet?

Answer (score 1):

When thinking about supporting a range of devices, you shouldn't be focusing on one specific device. The the beauty (and struggle) of working with Android. There are TONS of devices, with different sizes of screens and densities.

I highly recommend taking a look at this documentation,

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It will help you model your app in a way such that it will look great on a lot of devices.

The gist of it is this:
For drawables, you will need to create a number of different images to support different screen densities.

Here is a good tool I use to help with resizing my images: https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer

Comment: my app already support different devices screen, the only one where images doesn't fit well is the galaxy tab 3

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049659/understanding-samsung-galaxy-tab-screen-density